# Reference Abstract Model in Join Table for Many-to-Many in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models, with publication needing a m2m with authors via the join table specified, I have done this but keep getting the error:

```
Error: One or more models did not validate:
publications.workshop: 'staff' is a manually-defined m2m relation through model AuthorsJoinTable, which does not have foreign keys to Staff and Workshop
publications.technicalreport: 'staff' is a manually-defined m2m relation through model          AuthorsJoinTable, which does not have foreign keys to Staff and TechnicalReport
publications.authorsjointable: 'publication' has a relation with model Publication, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
publications.authorsjointable: "unique_together" refers to staff, a field that doesn't exist. Check your syntax.
```

My models look like:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    staff = models.ManyToManyField("personnel.Staff", related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related', through='AuthorsJoinTable')
    tag = models.ManyToManyField("Tag", related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related')
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Workshop(Publication):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    workshop_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    def __unicode__(self):  
        return u'%s - %s' % (self.title, self.workshoptitle)

class TechnicalReport(Publication):
    published_date = models.DateField()

class AuthorsJoinTable(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey("Author", related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_from')
    publication = models.ForeignKey("Publication", related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_to')
    order = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('staff', 'publication')

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    biography = models.TextField()
```

So how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> publications.authorsjointable: "unique_together" refers to staff, a field that doesn't exist. Check your syntax.

You can't create a ForeignKey on absract model because that model does not have a table in DB and therefore does not have primary key to reference. So you should make your `Publication` non-abstract or reference `Workshop` instead. Other error lines should also be gone after that.